# Javascript - need explanation on the variable inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, frontend, web-frontend

I have this code - I just wonder why after I add 'var' to foo variable, it doesn't work (it shows me foo is undefined)... Can anyone help explain these two functions? Thanks!

```
window.onload = function() {
    var test = foo().steps(2);
    console.log(test);
}

(function() {
  //if I remove var, then it prints out a function which is what I expected
  var foo = function() {
    var steps = 1;
    function callMe(g) {
      //do something else
      console.log("hello" + g);
    }
    callMe.steps = function(x) {
      //if no arguments then return the default value
      if (!arguments.length) return steps;
      console.log(arguments);
      //otherwise assign the new value and attached the value to callMe
      steps = x;
      return callMe;
    }
    return callMe;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Because `var` variables are function-scoped. You use `foo` outside the function it’s declared in.

Comment: Any idea on how to make it accessible to outside scope ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the link is really helpful... Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `var` to foo makes foo a local variable inside the IIFE and thus you can't access it outside.

Comment: Can you advise how to expose foo to outside?

Comment: @catlovespurple Declare `foo` outside the function and define it inside the function.

Comment: @Xufox can u just write some code to illustrate your suggestion? It's kind of hard to understand exactly what you mean here...

Comment: @catlovespurple Have you Googled “javascript variable declaration” or “javascript variable scope” before writing that comment?

Comment: @catlovespurple declare `var foo;` outside the IIFE and assign foo inside the IIFFE

Comment: @Xufox it's not about if I did Google, it's about your comment is not clear. Now I understand, thanks .